# How to write equivalent of SQL MERGE statement using Prisma?

Tags: sql, prisma, prisma2

I have a GraphQL mutation accepting the list of tag for a post. The `PostTag` model is:

```
model PostTag {
  id        BigInt          @id @default(autoincrement())

  order     Int
  value     String

  post      Post            @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId    BigInt          @map("post_id")
  

  @@map("post_tag")
}
```

My REST API is `PUT /posts/{postId}/tags` which receives the list of tags that is to be updated against a given `Post`. In this list, some tags could have `id` which means it is an existing `tag` item that should be updated. There would be `tag` items without `id` means, it should be newly added. And the missing tags against a given post means those tags should be deleted.

I can do this using SQL merge statement. I want to achieve similar result using Prisma. How to do that efficiently using **Prisma**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing, there's no equivalent to the `merge` statement. A workaround using two queries would be as follows:

1. Delete existing `PostTag` records connected to a specific `Post` with `deleteMany`.
2. Create new `PostTag` records from the data received from the API endpoint with `createMany`.

Preferably, you can wrap query 1 and 2 in a [transaction](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api) to ensure the database is not in an inconsistent state.

This isn't as optimized as the `merge` command. If you need the flexibility and performance of that specifically, please consider creating a [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) in the prisma repo mentioning your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your MERGE query as plain SQL using prisma.$exectureRaw